# Open a link from a Iframe(fancybox) in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, raphael

I'm building an Europe Map with raphael script using fancybox popup when clicking on country, it's displaying an `iframe`.

When clicking on a link inside the `iframe` the new page opened inside the `iframe` but i would like to open the link in a new window.

Here my script for raphael :

```
greek[state].click(function(){
  $j.fancybox({
   'showCloseButton': true,
   'href'   : 'link.html',
   'width'  : 500,
   'height' : 350,
   'type' : 'iframe'
  });
});
```

the link.html file is :

```
<a onclick="window.open(this.href,'','resizable=yes,location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,fullscreen=no,dependent=no,width=400,height=500,left=350,top=250,status'); return false" href="http://www.test.com"><img src="test-simotas.jpg" width="447" height="314"/></a>
```

i can't find a solution.

Do you have any idea?? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work:

```
<a 
onclick="window.open(this.['data-href'],
  '','resizable=yes,location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,
  toolbar=no,fullscreen=no,dependent=no,width=400,height=500,left=350,
  top=250,status'); return false" data-href="http://www.test.com"
  href="javascript:return false;">
```

Comment: Thanks it works but i had to change like this <a onclick="window.open(this.['data-href'],'','resizable=yes,location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,fullscreen=no,dependent=no,width=400,height=500,left=350,top=250,status'); return false" data-href="http://www.simotas.gr" href="http://www.simotas.gr" target="_blank"><img src="test-simotas.jpg" width="447" height="314"/></a>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it works but i had to change :

```
<a onclick="window.open(this.['data-href'],'','resizable=yes,location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,fullscreen=no,dependent=no,width=400,height=500,left=350,top=250,status'); return false" data-href="http://www.simotas.gr" href="http://test.com" target="_blank"><img src="test-simotas.jpg" width="447" height="314"/></a>
```